# Div inside of a <td>?

Tags: html, html-table

Is it valid to have a div inside of a `<td>` element? I need to display a box inside of the table..

Update:

I need this box (that appears in the td) to have padding..i.e. it really needs to look like a box that's floating in the middle of the td.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `div` element inside a `td` element is perfectly valid according to the XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD.

```
<!ELEMENT td       %Flow;>

<!ENTITY % Flow "(#PCDATA | %block; | form | %inline; | %misc;)*">

<!ENTITY % block
    "p | %heading; | div | %lists; | %blocktext; | fieldset | table">
```

Comment: Citation of standards deserves +2

Answer (score 1):

It is a question of **semantic markup**, yes you can have a `div` inside the `td`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is valid, but a cell is a box, no?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also could do a `<span>` inside the `<td>`

Comment: I assume it was meant to be "I guess you also could do a [HTML ELEMENT] inside the [HTML ELEMENT]" adn that it got stripped... seems harsh from whoever marked him down for a mistake in markup... :)

Comment: sorry about that :P Weird that the editor didn't warn me, or just did a replace of < to &lt; etc...

Answer (score 0):

Valid?  Perhaps.  Good HTML?  Maybe not.

Your best option, if you're already (stuck) using tables, is to put another `table` within the `td`.

Or you could just create the `div` inside the `td` and go on with your day, and not worry about it as long as it works.

Comment: Prima facie, you have no grounds for saying this should be a table or a div - without context you cannot judge what is semantically correct - but the only possible guess you could make is for a div here since "a box" is highly unlikely to be tabular data which would justify a nested table.

Comment: You're right; I was thinking more in terms of the don't-mix-div/span-and-tables style.